# Which design pattern separates determining what to do from doing it?

Tags: design-patterns

Which design (anti?) pattern includes a method which determines what needs to be done, and returns a list of "do this" items to the caller? The idea is to decouple the decision from the action.

Comment: Factory pattern.  todoList = todoFactory.GetTasks(some parameters)

Comment: Perhaps a [rules engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_rules_engine).

Comment: Why the downvote? Seems like a question that gets 4 different answers can't be that bad.

Comment: Four different answers is an indication of how unclear the question is: everyone has a different guess. Additionally, "This question does not show any research effort." And finally, it is not useful because Command Pattern is the accepted answer; but Command Pattern does not "_decouple the decision from the action._" It decouples the action from the execution of the action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the command pattern?

Here you specify the task

```
interface ICommand {
  void Execute();
}

class ProcessSomething: ICommand {

  public void Execute(){ 
  /* do stuff* /

 }
```

... elsewhere you return the list of do this items

```
var task = new ProcessSomething() {

}
```

...and even later you actually execute

```
task.Execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

[Model-view-controller](https://lkubaski.wordpress.com/2012/12/20/java-se-application-design-with-mvc-with-images/) has a goal that is similar to what you describe. [One objective of the views is to *recognize gestures*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/234167/51948), which is like determining *what* needs to be done. Depending on how your controller and model classes work, the *how* is accomplished by them.

You actually don't need to see it as MVC per se. A *presentation layer* (e.g., HTML or voice-recognition à la Siri or Hey Google, etc.) determines the *what* from the human user, and the so-called *domain layer* with its domain logic determines the *how*.